# Link Option Sets in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to create linked Option Sets in some contract forms to allow for a main type and multiple subtypes specific to each main type in the first option set. This does not seem to have functionality without some coding.

Abstract Ex:

Main Type Table: {A, B, C, ...}

Subtype Tables: {A1, A2, A3, ...} , {B1, B2, B3, ...}

I would like to create an option set that dynamically changes once a main type is selected, but don't know where to start with writing the code.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write some code, yes. I wrote [this blog article](http://thecrmgrid.wordpress.com/2007/11/13/a-slightly-different-approach-to-dynamic-picklists/) for version 4, but it might give you some pointers for version 2011.

Fundamentally, you will be writing a JScript web resource which:
 - contains a handler (function) hides or removes values from your "Subtype" picklist, if the record has no value in that field. This should be registered against the form's `onLoad` event handler
 - contains a handler (function) that can be registered against the `onChange` event handler of your "Main Type" picklist that will look at the newly selected value and filter/populate your "Subtype" picklist as appropriate

If writing clientside JScript code for CRM 2011 is unfamiliar to you, then you should review [the appropriate part of the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328255.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Add an OnChange event to the MainType dropdown, and then perform an Odata Rest call to populate the values in the subtype.

What part do you need help with?